# C++ Pointer to Numpy Array

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

**Briefly:**

Is there an efficient way to make a numpy array given a pointer in memory to the array, it's type, and the number of elements?

**More detail:**

I am working with a python framework which has an `object.GetData()` command that is supposed to return a pointer to the data (an array of 35,000 int8) of this object.

I'm supposed to be able efficiently load these integers to a numpy array through

```
arr = numpy.frombuffer(object.GetData(),count=35000,dtype="int8")
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I get an error message `ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size`. Changing the length, I can get it to output an array, but typically less than 20 integers in length (usually 0 or 1 integers).

I believe I can access the pointer to the start of the array, in hex form, through

```
hex(id(object.GetData()))
```

which looks like it gives addresses (e.g. 0x10fd8c670) but I don't know if this is the actual address.

I'm more comfortable in python than c++, but there could be a bug in the c++ code. The c++ code for GetData is:

```
const _Tp* GetData() const 
{ 
  // Return a const pointer to the internal data
  return (fData.size() > 0 ) ? &(fData)[0] : NULL; 
}
```

where fdata is initialized as a VecType through:

```
VecType   fData;
```

Right now I can access each element of the object's data through an `object.At(i)` command where i is the index of the data array of object, but it is very slow to load each element into a numpy array this way, and I'm dealing with a lot of data. For reference, the At command in the c++ code does this:

```
_Tp  At(size_t i) const 
{ 
  return fData.at(i); 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I don't have a ton of experience with pointers, and even less with pointers in python, but I would like to figure this out in python rather than re-write all my code in c++. Thanks!

Comment: "supposed to return a pointer to the data" - hold on. What data type do you mean by "pointer"? Is this return value a ctypes pointer? A memoryview? An integer representing a memory address? What is it?